# How do I download old official container images of Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

When I pulled ubuntu:18.04 official image from docker hub, I got Ubuntu **18.04.4** image, but I want Ubuntu 18.04 base image. What is the way to download older official images like 18.04/18.04.1/18.04.2/18.04.3?

root@50d9e7e557b8:/BUILD# cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DESCRIPTION
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu **18.04.4** LTS"

Comment: please put additional information like which exact command you tried to pull image and how you are verifying (put command expecitly if any) what got downloded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to download container image corresponding to Ubuntu-18.04 without any updates, by following below stesp.

1. Figured out that Ubuntu-18.04 was released on 26th Apr 2018 from
   http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/. Just checked the
   timestamp of ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso file.
2. Sorted ubuntu images on docker hub by name and figured out container image name  corresponding to 18.04 GA is bionic-**20180426** based on
   GA date of 18.04 release. Refer this link -
   https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu?tab=tags&page=2&ordering=-name.
3. Pulled ubuntu:bionic-20180426 image, created an instance out of it and checked contents of lsb-release file.

   root@e7967ee0869d:/# cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DESCRIPTION

   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu **18.04** LTS"

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you want to [pull an image by digest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier), not by tag. However, I'm not sure how you'd figure out which digest you want. This is the [commit history](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/commits/master/library/ubuntu) of the file that would contain that info.